# Why does this print 3 A's?

Tags: java

It returns 3 A's but I don't see why that is?

Here is my code:
        for a certain `int[] array = {3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3};`

```
public static void returns(int[]array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i+= 2) {
        if (array[i] == 3) {
            System.out.print("A");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What you probably overlooked: `i+= 2`

Comment: @Tunaki does that mean that the array is being incremented by two? so 1+2 = 3 no?

Comment: The iterations only look at elements 0 (3),2 (2), 4 (3) ,6 (1), and 8 (3).  Only three of those are '3' so 'A' gets printed 3 times.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) about the `for` loop.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Oh my mistake i thought it was adding 2 to each element I don't know why sorry for the bother!

Comment: Just to make sure it won't be missed: `i += 2` is the same as `i = i  + 2`, so it `i` is incremented by *2* _each_ iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Because with an initial value of zero for `i` (and `i+= 2`) you are only testing the even indices, and of those only 0 4 and 8 are 3. You could use something like

```
System.out.printf("%d A ", i);
```

Instead of `System.out.print("A");` to see for yourself.

I get

```
0 A 4 A 8 A
```

If you wanted to count the `3`(s), I'd prefer a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Also, pass in the desired value. Something like

```
public static int count(int[] array, int value) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i : array) {
        if (i == value) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```